# IdentityServer4 Microsoft provider callbackpath not found in Azure environment

Tags: c#, azure, identityserver4

here is my problem (that only happens when publishing my Identity server in Azure)

I configured Identity to support login with Google and Microsoft. 
Google works fine but if I choose Microsoft, its going to Microsoft Login without issues and after the login, when Microsoft is trying to redirect to our callback is giving not found.  https://server/signin-microsoft?code=...&session_state=... .

Using same stuff but with Identity Server hosted in a localhost url is working fine.
Google is configured the same way and is working without issues.

Any idea what can I test or how I can troubleshoot this?

Thanks!
Andres

Comment: can you check if the flow is actually what you say with browsers developer tools. If you use Chrome, use the preserve log checkbox so that you see the network from start to end. May be there is a redirect happening somewhere in that pipeline? Also enable logs for the IdSrv so that you can see any errors happening during that transition.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the issue and the problem was that the url was too long when Microsoft redirect to the IdentityServer. 
Just had to extend accepted query string to be a bit longer.

Comment: Where and how did you "extend accepted query string to be a bit longer" ? I seem to have exactly the same problem.